# Get the best from a Gaggia Unica coffee machine

Tags: cleaning, maintenance, quality, bean-to-cup

I have a Gaggia Unica bean-to-cup machine and I want to use this machine to get the best quality coffee possible.

How should I use and maintain/clean the machine to ensure the highest standard of coffee possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest your first port of call should be the operators manual. Here is an excerpt:

• Empty and clean the coffee grounds drawer daily, with the machine turned on.
• After having removed the coffee grounds drawer, remove the liquids from the tray placed under the brew group.

Note: We recommend emptying the container if the machine is not going to be used for some days.

After brewing milk beverages, dispense hot water from the steam wand (Pannarello, if supplied) to obtain a thorough cleaning.

- Every day, after heating the milk, remove the external part of the Pannarello (if supplied) and wash it with fresh drinking water.
- Clean the steam wand weekly. To do this, the following operations have to
  be performed:
- Remove the external part of the Pannarello (for standard cleaning);
- Remove the upper part of the Pannarello from the steam wand;
- Wash the upper part of the Pannarello with fresh drinking water;
- Wash the steam wand with a wet cloth and remove any milk residues;
- Replace the upper part in the steam wand (make sure it is completely inserted).
  Reassemble the external part of the Pannarello.
- It is recommended to clean the water tank daily. For an easier removal of the
  water tank, move the steam wand / Pannarello upwards:
- Remove the small white filter in the water tank and wash it under running drinking water.
- Reposition the small white filter in its housing by gently pressing and turning it at the same time.
- Fill the tank with fresh drinking water.
- Empty and clean the drip tray daily. Perform this operation also when the float is raised.